# Boost preprocessor to pass all struct arguments in a function

Tags: c++, boost, preprocessor

Is it possible to pass all the members of a struct in a function using boost preprocessor APIs
I have something like this but does not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/variadic_seq_to_seq.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/elem.hpp>

// Define a macro to generate code for passing a struct member to a function
#define PASS_MEMBER_TO_FUNCTION(r, structName, elem) \
    function(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, elem), structName.BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, elem));

// Define a macro to iterate over struct members and pass them to a function
#define PASS_MEMBERS_TO_FUNCTION(structName, members) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(PASS_MEMBER_TO_FUNCTION, structName, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SEQ_TO_SEQ(members))

// Example struct
struct MyStruct {
    int height;
    double width;
    const char* name;
};

// Example function that takes struct members
void function(int value, double width, const char* name) {
    // Your function implementation here
    std::cout << "Value: " << value << ", Width: " << width << ", Name: " << name << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // Usage example
    MyStruct myStruct{10, 20.5, "example"};
    PASS_MEMBERS_TO_FUNCTION(myStruct, ((int, height))((double, width))((const char*, name)));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend looking into one of the struct reflection libraries out there such as Boost.PFR. For an aggregate like this, they can give you a tuple of the members without the preprocessor. They still need to hack around the lack of reflection support of course, but the preprocessor isn't needed.

Comment: Is not possible to do this using boost preprocessor?

Comment: It's _possible_, but it comes with the regular flaws, plus you're duplicating all the member names in the call whereas an actual C++ API would only take `myStruct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Boost PFR you don't need a preprocessor:

```
std::apply(function, boost::pfr::structure_tie(myStruct));
```

Demo **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56ed4ea7f9eeace4)**:

```cpp
#include <boost/pfr.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct {
    int         height;
    double      width;
    char const* name;
};

// Example function that takes separate parameters
void function(int value, double width, char const* name) {
    std::cout << "Value: " << value << ", Width: " << width << ", Name: " << name << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // Usage example
    MyStruct myStruct{10, 20.5, "example"};
    apply(function, boost::pfr::structure_tie(myStruct));
}
```

Printing

```
Value: 10, Width: 20.5, Name: example
```